# Displaying data from one page to another

Tags: asp.net

I have a page (default.aspx) with a Repeater fetching data from my database, this is the layout for the Repeater:

**default.aspx:**

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Id","~/fullpost.aspx?Id={0}") %>'><asp:Literal ID="LitTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:Literal></asp:HyperLink>
                            <br />
                            <span class="textSum">
                                <asp:Literal ID="LitSummary" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Summary") %>'></asp:Literal></span>
                            <span class="dateTime">
                                <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CreateDateTime") %>'></asp:Literal></span>
```

Notice the hyperlink now, it directs to **fullpost.aspx**, On this page I want to display only that one item I clicked (the URL is being pointed right, it goes to **fullpost.aspx?Id=*IdNumber***), so I tried the following:

**fullpost.aspx:**

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:Literal>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:orangefreshConnectionString1 %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [Title], [Summary], [Body], [CreateDateTime] FROM [Post] WHERE ([Id] = @Id)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Id" QueryStringField="Id" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

But my literal is not displaying the Title as I want it to, nothing shows up. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

---

After adding the data bound control:

```
 <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:Literal>
    </asp:FormView>
```

I'm now getting:
*Parser Error Message: Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView' does not have a public property named 'Literal'.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Literal1` on fullpost.aspx is not inside a [data bound control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228214.aspx) to get its data from the `SqlDataSource`.  Put it inside something like a `FormView` with it's data source set to `SqlDataSource1`.

*EDIT* example FormView

The [FormView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.aspx) contains a tag called `<ItemTemplate>` which contains the controls you want to display.  NOTE: If you use an IDE like [Visual Web Developer](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express), it will automatically create the correct tag structure for you.

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Comment: Stupid of me not to remember the data bound control... still, I'm getting an error now, will update first post.

Comment: Cheers bud, I don't know why VWD didn't create the markup for me... thanks a lot for your help.